# Multiple lines of output in a message box, assembly language

Tags: assembly, messagebox, inline-assembly

I have created this program to calculate the credits needed to graduate from a basic user input of name, degree, credits needed for degree, and current credits earned. Assembly is new to me and up to this point have only been taught the basics of I/O and message boxes, in this case "labels." Although I was only asked to output via message box the credits needed for degree I thought it might be fun to explore how to display the user entered name and degree as well. My program displays the name and degree in one message box and the needed credits in another. My question is, would it be possible to combine both boxes into one that displays both sets of outputs? Thanks in advance.

```
.586
.MODEL FLAT

INCLUDE io.h            ; header file for input/output

.STACK 4096
.DATA

student_name DWORD   ?
student_degree DWORD   ?
credits_needed DWORD    ?
credits_completed DWORD ?

prompt1 BYTE    "Please enter your name and degree: ", 0
stringIn    BYTE    80 DUP (?)
displayLbl  BYTE    "Student Name - Student Degree...", 0
stringOut   BYTE    80 DUP (?)

prompt2 BYTE    "How many credits in your degree field?", 0
prompt3 BYTE    "Lastly, how many credits have your earned?", 0
string      BYTE    60 DUP (?)
resultLbl BYTE  "Credits needed for your chosen degree", 13,10
sum     BYTE    11 DUP (?), 0

.CODE
_MainProc PROC
        input   prompt1, stringIn, 80   ;ask for string of student name and degree
        lea     eax, stringIn           ;source
        push    eax
        lea     eax, stringOut
        push    eax
        call    strcopy
        add     esp, 8

        input   prompt2, string, 60
        atod    string
        mov     credits_needed, eax

        input   prompt3, string, 60
        atod    string
        mov     credits_completed, eax

        mov     eax, credits_needed   ; credits needed to EAX
        sub     eax, credits_completed    ; subtract credits earned     
        dtoa    sum, eax        ; convert to ASCII characters       

        output  displayLbl, stringOut
        output  resultLbl, sum  ; output label and sum

        mov     eax, 0  ; exit with return code 0
        ret

    _MainProc ENDP

strcopy PROC NEAR32
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp
        push    edi
        push    esi
        pushfd

        mov     edi, [ebp+8]
        mov esi, [ebp+12]
        cld
whileNoNull:
        cmp     BYTE PTR [esi], 0
        je      endWhileNoNull
        movsb
        jmp     whileNoNull
endWhileNoNull:
        mov     BYTE PTR [edi],0

        popfd
        pop     esi
        pop     edi
        pop     ebp
        ret
strcopy ENDP
END                             ; end of source code
```

It was brought to my attention that without seeing the io.h resource it would be impossible to tell so here it is:

```
.586
EXTRN _getInput:NEAR32, _showOutput:NEAR32, atodproc:NEAR32, dtoaproc:NEAR32, wtoaproc:NEAR32, atowproc:NEAR32


dtoa        MACRO  dest,source         ; convert double to ASCII string
            push   ebx                 ; save EBX
            lea    ebx, dest           ; destination address
            push   ebx                 ; destination parameter
            mov    ebx, [esp+4]        ; in case source was EBX
            mov    ebx, source         ; source value
            push   ebx                 ; source parameter
            call   dtoaproc            ; call dtoaproc(source,dest)
            add    esp, 8              ; remove parameters
            pop    ebx                 ; restore EBX
            ENDM

atod        MACRO  source              ; convert ASCII string to integer in EAX
            lea    eax,source          ; source address to AX
            push   eax                 ; source parameter on stack
            call   atodproc            ; call atodproc(source)
            add    esp, 4              ; remove parameter
            ENDM

wtoa        MACRO  dest,source         ; convert word to ASCII string
            push   ebx                 ; save EBX
            lea    ebx,dest            ; destination address
            push   ebx                 ; destination parameter
            mov    ebx, [esp+4]        ; in case source was BX
            mov    bx, source          ; source value
            push   ebx                 ; source parameter
            call   wtoaproc            ; call dtoaproc(source,dest)
            add    esp, 8              ; remove parameters
            pop    ebx                 ; restore EBX
            ENDM

atow        MACRO  source              ; convert ASCII string to integer in AX
            lea    eax,source          ; source address to AX
            push   eax                 ; source parameter on stack
            call   atowproc            ; call atodproc(source)
            add    esp, 4              ; remove parameter
            ENDM

output      MACRO  outLbl, outStr      ; display label and string

            pushad                     ; save general registers
            cld                        ; clear DF
            lea    eax,outStr          ; string address
            push   eax                 ; string parameter on stack
            lea    eax,outLbl          ; label address
            push   eax                 ; string parameter on stack
            call   _showOutput         ; showOutput(outLbl, outStr)
            add    esp, 8              ; remove parameters
            popad                      ; restore general registers
            ENDM

input       MACRO  inPrompt, inStr, maxLength     ; prompt for and input  string
            pushad                     ; save general registers
            mov    ebx, maxLength      ; length of input string
            push   ebx                 ; length parameter on stack
            lea    ebx,inStr           ; destination address
            push   ebx                 ; dest parameter on stack
            lea    ebx,inPrompt        ; prompt address
            push   ebx                 ; prompt parameter on stack
            call   _getInput           ; getInput(inPrompt, inStr, maxLength)
            add    esp, 12             ; remove parameters
            popad                      ; restore general registers
            ENDM

.NOLISTMACRO ; suppress macro expansion listings
.LIST        ; begin listing
```

Comment: Without the code for `input` and `output` it's not really possible to tell. They are probably macros defined in `io.h`

Comment: I was pre-supplied with the resource files. I supposes I can post those.

Comment: without them it's not possible to answer your question :P

Answer (score 1):

> would it be possible to combine both boxes into one that displays both sets of outputs?

It's easy to show both sets of information in one go if you copy the input from *stringIn* higher up in the *stringOut* buffer and at the same time have *resultLbl* and *sum* adjacent to the *stringOut* buffer.

### Step 1, make buffers adjacent

```
displayLbl  BYTE  "Student Name - Student Degree...", 0
stringOut   BYTE  80 DUP (?), 10
resultLbl   BYTE  "Credits needed for your chosen degree", 13,10
sum         BYTE  11 DUP (?), 0
```

Note the extra linefeed character after *stringOut*!

### Step 2, copy higher up in the *stringOut* buffer

```
input   prompt1, stringIn, 80   ;ask for string of student name and degree
lea     eax, stringIn           ;source
push    eax
call    szlen                   ;Gives length in EAX
mov     ebx, stringOut+79       ;Position for the terminating zero
sub     ebx, eax                ; minus the length
push    ebx
call    strcopy
add     esp, 8
mov     byte ptr [stringOut+79], 13

...     other stuff that doesn't clobber EBX
```

The crucial thing here is to replace the terminating zero written by *strcopy* with a carriage return so that all texts are seemlessly connected.

### Step 3, display in one go

```
output  displayLbl, [ebx]
```

---

This is how *szlen* macro is defined in *io.h*:

```
szlen       MACRO  string              ; get string length
            lea    eax, string         ; string address
            push   eax                 ; string parameter on stack
            call   szlenproc           ; call szlenproc(string)
            ENDM
```

This is how the *szlenproc* procedure looks like:

```
; szlenproc(source)
; Procedure to calculate length of a null-terminated string
; No registers are changed; flags are not affected.

szlenproc   PROC   NEAR32
            push   ebp                 ; save base pointer
            mov    ebp, esp            ; establish stack frame
            pushad
            pushfd                     ; save flags

            mov    esi,[ebp+8]         ; source address
            mov    strAddr, esi

; find string length
            mov    strLength, 0        ; initialize string length
WhileChar:  cmp    BYTE PTR [esi], 0   ; character = null?
            jz     EndWhileChar        ; exit if so
            inc    strLength           ; increment character count
            inc    esi                 ; point at next character
            jmp    WhileChar
EndWhileChar:
            popfd                      ; restore flags
            popad                      ; restore registers
            pop    ebp 
            mov    eax, strLength      ; rerun string length in EAX
            ret    4                   ;exit, discarding parameter
szlenproc   ENDP
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!